# How to print items of list without braces in dart?

Tags: arrays, list, flutter, dart, printing

I am a beginner in dart and I want to print the last items of a multidimensional array.

what for loop code gives:
[ [ Item1 ], [ Item1, Item2 ] ]

what I want to print is the last list items like:
**Item1, Item2**

I have tried for loop but I failed
please, help me

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
 [[Item1], [Item1, Item2]].forEach((list) {
   print(list.last);
 });
```